# Virtualbox running on VMWare VM on ESXi

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox, vmware

I am trying to run my Chef/Kitchen tests that use Vagrant/Virtualbox on an ESXi VMWare cluster guest to test cookbook integration.  I will likely move to a VMWare version for Kitchen/Vagrant and remove the Virtualbox portion at some point but would like to see this work first.

I have the virtualization support turned on in the VM so it does function, but it is excruciatingly slow.  Where the full converge on my desktop is done in under 4 minutes, it takes nearly 40 minutes in the VM.  Checking perfomance on the VMWare VM and it seems acceptable, but the VirtualBox VM inside it has very high Hardware Interrupt service.  All other metrics seem to be about average.  Where HI rarely gets about 1-2 under normal systems it is steady >30 even while idle in the Virtualbox guest and often above 50.

Any ideas on what to look for or magic settings I may have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the very helpful article linked to by itfdev at https://egustafson.github.io/esxi-nested-virtualbox.html I have found that what I want to do will likely always be slow due to the quote below:

> Disk Performance
> During my initial experimentation with nested VM’s I observed a clear decrease in performance of the nested VM. My initial experimentation mostly only went as far as installing the OS on the nested VM. Installing an OS is generally a disk intensive activity.
>
> Disk virtualization is more expensive than most. Nesting virtualized disks will accumulate "virtualization debt" quicker than other virtualized components. The short, but rambling explanation goes something like this:

> > In my inner VM I write a block to "disk". This traverses the inner OS’s file system code and is mapped to a sector on the inner VM’s virtual block device.  Writing is the passed to the outer VM, traverses the file system code, and is  mapped to the outer VM’s virtual block device. Finally, the block is passed to  the host, (physical), file system, mapped through to a sector, and finally
> > placed on the actual physical device. — If your head is spinning now, it
> > should be. That’s three times the block is passed through file system code on it’s eventual path to a physical write.
>
> This problem is understood in the virtualization community, and there are methods for avoiding differing degrees of the penalty based on the requirements of an installation. I will not cover these here. My point: if your nested VM’s strike you as slow, this may be a significant part of the why.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox, running in the virtual environment, can only use "software" virtualization. It's slow, of course. It should consume a lot of processor time. ESXi in a host system use hardware acceleration (VT-x or similar), and it performance close to real host performance. You should not install VM on VM.

Comment: VirtualBox inside is using VT-x to get 64bit compatibility.  It was something I had to turn on for the hosting VM to pass through to the Virtualbox VM.

Comment: If you really need this... Have you read this article? https://egustafson.github.io/esxi-nested-virtualbox.html

Comment: there was a good secition of that link that pretty much answers why it is and likely always will be slow.